# Having problems with my phone please help :(

Tags: applications, lg-g6

My phone has been making these weird blue and red shapes for a while now and I have no idea how to turn it off, anyone got any ideas?

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 2):

This could be the result of enabling the developer option: Show layout bounds. If that is not the case you could try backing up your data and factory reseting your phone. This will delete all your apps and all user(s) info resetting all your settings to default and returning the phone to its factory state.

Your SD card will be deleted as well so remove it before the reset. So any apps that you dont have an apk file for you will need to download and install again. You can then use your backed up data to restore the apps to thier original configuration in many cases. Take care not to use any suspicious apps from questionable sources. If you installed some sort of app with permission to write over other apps this could be the cause as well.

Comment: Great answer, but the questioner probably doesn't know what that option is. It might  be worthwhile explaining better how to find it and turn it off, rather than going straight to a lengthy description of a factory reset.

Comment: noted. thanks mod. could you have a peek at my one and only question at your convenience?